# Setting up SSL with sockjs

Tags: node.js, websocket

How do I install an https/ssl certificate (and key) in sockjs (running on nodejs)?

I'm currently running the most basic setup, this is, the "echo" example setup. It is a follows:

```
var http = require('http');
var sockjs = require('sockjs');
var node_static = require('node-static');

// 1. Echo sockjs server
var sockjs_opts = {sockjs_url: "http://cdn.sockjs.org/sockjs-0.3.min.js"};

var sockjs_echo = sockjs.createServer(sockjs_opts);
sockjs_echo.on('connection', function(conn) {
    conn.on('data', function(message) {
        conn.write(message);
    });
});

// 2. Static files server
var static_directory = new node_static.Server(__dirname);

// 3. Usual http stuff
var server = http.createServer();
server.addListener('request', function(req, res) {
    static_directory.serve(req, res);
});
server.addListener('upgrade', function(req,res){
    res.end();
});

sockjs_echo.installHandlers(server, {prefix:'/echo'});

console.log(' [*] Listening on 0.0.0.0:9999' );
server.listen(9999, '0.0.0.0');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay I got it to work by changing the code to:

```
var http = require('https');
var sockjs = require('sockjs');
var fs = require("fs");

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('ssl.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl.crt')
};

var echo = sockjs.createServer();
echo.on('connection', function(conn) {
    conn.on('data', function(message) {
        conn.write(message);
    });
    conn.on('close', function() {});
});

var server = http.createServer(options);
echo.installHandlers(server, {prefix:'/echo'});
server.listen(9999, '0.0.0.0');
```

Comment: If you're using a self-signed certificate (say, for local development) then you'll need to confirm the security exception for SSL or the websockets will not connect. Just go to `http://localhost:9999/info` (or whatever host/port you're using) and follow the prompts that your browser will give you.

Comment: Any idea of how to do this programmatically when using [sockjs-client-node](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client-node)?